# Unable to launch any avd from Android studio's virtual device manager

Tags: android-studio, android-virtual-device, avd-manager

I'm new to Android Studio, but I have been looking for an answer for the past two days and no answer seems to fix my problem.

When I am in avd manager in Android studio, I see the list of devices, but nothing happens at all when I click the launch button. No error message, no loading screen/bar etc.

[AVD manager screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHEz3.png)

when I run the "android list avd" command line, I get the following error message

"The following Android Virtual Devices could not be loaded:
    Name: Pixel_2_XL_API_23
    Path: C:\Users\nicol.android\avd\Pixel_2_XL_API_23.avd
   Error: Google pixel_2_xl no longer exists as a device"

[Error message screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjVpK.png)

This error appears with every avd I created, even with custom ones that I defined myself. 
I found answers saying that making some modifications in the devices.xml file in the .android folder could solve this problem, but I could not find any file named devices.xml in the .android folder, or anywhere else.

PS. I'm trying to setup a developing environment for React Native, that's why the target in avd manager is Android 6.0. But I have exactly the same problem when I try to use different versions of Android.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I've been struggling with this for a while. Thanks!